# iPhone won't open Safari - or other - pages

Tags: iphone, safari

Has anyone found a fix to this yet? I have upgraded to IOS 9.3. I have reset my iPhone. But it still won't open links.

Comment: IOS9.3.1 is out and it fixed the problem. Thank you! http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/138476/redeagle2000 http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujinhttp://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in iOS 9. Not much to do but wait for an update.

Comment: IOS9.3.1 is out and it fixed the problem.